# How to display all weeks of current month in Full Calendar agendaWeek view - Angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using ngx-fullcalendar plugin in angular to display all weeks without using next-previous button of current month in agendaWeek view.
[image]

Comment: The "week" view displays exactly a week, always. The clue is in the name!!

Comment: P.S. "agendaWeek" does not exist in fullCalendar 4. It's in fullCalendar 3. Are you sure you have tagged the correct version? In v4 and above it's "timeGridWeek". In all the versions though, there is the "custom view" capability which lets you specify the number of days you want in your view - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/custom-view-with-settings (for v3) or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/custom-view-with-settings (for v4). Did you check any documentation before asking this question?